# I keep getting this error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to register a user but whenever I do I get an error, the same one that's in the title. I'm not sure if I should be defining data or not but I'm pretty stuck here.

auth/register.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert'; 
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL
} from './types';

// Register User
export const register = ({ name, email, password}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content- Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

    dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
    })
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_FAIL
    });
  }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which line is causing the error, `payload: res.data` or `const errors = err.response.data.errors`?

Comment: My guess is `err.response.data.errors` since the `catch` would catch any errors thrown in the `try` if it was `res.data`.

Comment: @DrewReese yes your correct

Comment: @Phil err.response.data.errors

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `res.response.data.errors` access in the `catch` block is throwing a new error that isn't being caught by your UI code.

While you should strive to write defensive UI code around asynchronous logic that is potentially rejected, I suggest using the Optional Chaining operator here to iterate over the errors array if it exists (*i.e. if you can access that deep into the error object*).

```
try {
  const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data
  })
} catch (err) {
  err.response?.data?.errors?.forEach(
    error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger'))
  );

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_FAIL
  });
}
```